# What are the best question-and-answer sequences on Buddhism?

Tags: personal-practice

If you would like to, suggest the -- let's say 10 -- best core question-and-answer sequences on this site ... which you would select to present (maybe for a tiny book "BSE and beyond - teachings on Dhamma", or a introduction link for a "new-comer" here).

Ideally an answer should provide a nice ["Step by Step" teaching](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/ptf/dhamma/index_en.html).

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma, not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gain by means of trade and exchange]*

Comment: Maybe move this question to meta site?

Comment: @ThiagoSilva It's an unusual question (and a polling question) but I wasn't inclined to close it. It might interest beginners (see also [The 'beginner' tag](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/396/254), and, [How about a 'resource' tab?](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1614/254)), or teachers, and others. It could be on Meta (because it's about the site) but IMO it could be here (because it's about Buddhism).

Comment: @ChrisW good thinking!

Comment: Maybe one likes to add a guiding frame: 1. The three Juwels, then On Generosity, then Virtue, Heaven, Drawbacks, Renunciation, The Noble Truth of Dukkha, The Noble Truth of the Cause of Dukkha, The Noble Truth of the Cessation of Dukkha, The Noble Truth of the Path Leading to the Cessation of Dukkha. To make it possible easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Rebirth**

1. I think that 'rebirth' is not the most important topic in Buddhism; but it is the topic which I thought I understood the least, and so it was the first topic which I asked about:

   [Is rebirth a delusional belief?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/3420/254)
2. It was later, in answering this question, that I hope I came to satisfactory understanding of the anatta doctrine:

   [How is it wrong to believe that a self exists, or that it doesn't?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/15898/254)
3. Furthermore, [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/19867/254) includes an attempt to summarize "What's the value or harm of a literal belief in rebirth?" -- but I don't know any better short summary than this comment ...

   > it's not that Buddhists believe in rebirth, it's that we don't believe in death

   from [the same answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/58/254); or than the folk-singer's doctrine which was summarized in [this answer](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/11682/254).

**Step by step**

- The OP posted [a comment](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/what-are-the-best-question-and-answer-sequences-on-buddhism#comment39330_23290) to give an example of what he meant by "step by step".
- Another way to sequence (doctrine and practice) might be the so-called [Threefold Training](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_Training).
- And, you might like to consider this list of [Useful resources](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) suggested by the users of this site.

But (apart from those) I posted some questions about the [Four stages of enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_stages_of_enlightenment) of Theravada Buddhism.

If I recommend the following, it's not that mine were good questions (I didn't know what I was asking about, maybe it's not useful to read the questions) but you may find the answers to these topics helpful:

4. [What are examples of identity-view?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/5862/254)
5. [How are 'conceit' and 'identity-view' not the same?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/9415/254)

**Pali canon**

If you go to a bookstore and look for books about Buddhism, it's easy to find many books written by modern authors.

In studying a religion, in the past I have often wanted to try to read the "original" doctrine and not only the more modern interpretations (if I were studying Christianity, for example, I would prefer to read the [red words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_edition) in the Gospels than to read anything else).

Anyway, I took advantage of this site to ask two other questions, about access to that literature:

6. [English (or other European) translations of Pali Canon](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4109/254)
7. [Chronological or other sequence for beginners](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/4112/254)

**Other forms/schools of Buddhism**

I find it, unfortunately, difficult to even ask sensible questions about other forms of Buddhism (I hope that other people may so that I can read the questions and the answers).

I recommend or remember the following as having given me some insight into at least the existence of forms (doctrines, practices, traditions) of Buddhism in addition to the Theravada of the Pali canon:

8. [How to explain what Buddhism is?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/7258/254)
9. [What is meant by Namu Amida Butsu and also Nam-myoho-renge-kyo?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/184/254)
10. [Pāramitāyāna and Tantrayāna](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/13703/254)